# How do I escape the # character in a VB.NET string literal?

Tags: .net, vb.net, escaping

If I needed to escape a double quote character within a string literal I'd use two consecutive double quotes as follows:

```
Dim name = "Chuck ""Iceman"" Liddell"
```

However, it doesn't seem like consecutive # works the same way.  The compiler is expecting a compiler directive to follow the # character, even when its enclosed in double quotes.  How can tell the compiler that I want a # character in my string?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** as a few of the answers below point out, `#` is not a reserved character.  I closed my solution in Visual Studio and re-opened it and no longer got the compiler squiggles warning me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#` is not a reserved character in a VB.NET string literal.

```
Dim test = "#" ' no error
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to escape it.  The code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MessageBox.Show("We're #1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

works fine as-is

(I took the time to write a whole new Windows app just to be sure on that one.)

Answer (score 3):

I am not seeing the behavior you described.  The following compiles just fine in Visual Studio 2008

```
Dim x = "#hello"
```

What version of Visual Studio are you running and can you give a more complete sample?

Answer (score 2):

eh? No compiler error here:

```
Dim s as String = "Hello # there"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to build a DateTime literal?

```
Dim d as DateTime = #12/10/2009#
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Dim name = @"#cakes" As String
```

or

```
Dim name = "\#cakes" As String
```

Comment: That's C# strings and VB.Net variable declarations